# How can I download last artifact in Artifactory?

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

I have some artifacts in Artifactory (OpenSource):

[image]

I can download an artifact from using **jfrog CLI**:

```
jfrog rt config --user=admin --password=**** --url=http://foo:8081/artifactory
jfrog rt download testproject/01_Develop/01_CI/HPCC-Package-70.zip --flat=true
```

**How can I download the LATEST(highest number) artifact?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the JFrog Cli [search command](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-SearchingFiles).

```
jfrog rt s "testproject/01_Develop/01_CI/HPCC-Package-*.zip"
```

The search command will return a list of paths which you can then sort using external tools such as jq.

Answer (score 23):

JFrog CLI recently started supporting 3 new options from many of the Artifactory commands: *--sort-by* *--sort-order* and *--limit*.

You can use these options to search, download, copy, move or delete the latest artifact created in Artifactory.  For example, to download the latest file uploaded to the *all-my-frogs* folder  in the *my-local-repo* repository, use the following command:

```
jfrog rt dl  "my-local-repo/all-my-frogs/" --sort-by=created
--sort-order=desc --limit=1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to do it from a Jenkins groovy file, you could use:

```
    def downloadSpec = """{
            "files": [
                {
                    "pattern": pattern,
                    "target": "",
                    "flat" : "true",
                    "sortBy": ["name"],
                    "sortOrder": "desc",
                    "limit": 1
                }
            ]
        }"""
```