# Unable to parse json output of artifactory with jq in linux

Tags: json, linux, artifactory, jq, skip

After executing this query in Artifactory

```
/usr/bin/jfrog rt s foo/01_Develop/01_CI/HPCC-Package-*.zip
```

I have this output:

```
[Info] Searching artifacts...
[Info] Found 3 artifacts.
[
  {
    "path": "foo/01_Develop/01_CI/HPCC-Package-47.zip"
  },
  {
    "path": "foo/01_Develop/01_CI/HPCC-Package-48.zip"
  },
  {
    "path": "foo/01_Develop/01_CI/HPCC-Package-72.zip"
  }
]
```

I want to get the last path in json array with this command as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41362345/how-can-i-download-last-artifact-in-artifactory):

```
/usr/bin/jfrog rt s foo/01_Develop/01_CI/HPCC-Package-*.zip | jq .[-1].path
```

But fails with

> parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 6

I cannot change json as it is the output from artifactory jfrog tool

- How can I fix JQ query?
- Is there any other way to get the last path?

NOTE: I have jq version 1.5

UPDATE:

Using quotes I have the exact same error:

```
/usr/bin/jfrog rt s foo/01_Develop/01_CI/HPCC-Package-*.zip | jq '.[-1].path'
/usr/bin/jfrog rt s foo/01_Develop/01_CI/HPCC-Package-*.zip | jq ".[-1].path"
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce using JQ 1.5 on Ubuntu.  Is your shell perhaps mangling the `[-1]`?  What happens if you put `.[-1].path` in quotes?

Comment: Added as update. With quotes I have the same  error

Comment: I have some headers in file, perhaps that is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, here's a jq-only solution that assumes there are exactly two lines of non-JSON prolog:

```
... | jq -n -R -r '[inputs][2:] | join("") | fromjson[-1]' 
{
  "path": "foo/01_Develop/01_CI/HPCC-Package-72.zip"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in previous answers, this error occurred because the output of JFrog CLI is not pure JSON.
You may want to set the JFROG_CLI_LOG_LEVEL environment variable to ERROR, so that additional messages will not be prompted by the command.
For more details you can read [JFrog CLI wiki.](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/Welcome+to+JFrog+CLI#WelcometoJFrogCLI-EnvironmentVariables)

Answer (score 3):

Your Artifactory output isn't pure json... you need to remove those non-json parts.  Assuming we will only need to skip the first two lines, we could just use tail to skip em.

```
/usr/bin/jfrog rt s foo/01_Develop/01_CI/HPCC-Package-*.zip | tail -n +3 | jq '.[-1].path'
```