# How to query the latest file and only pull down that file from JFrog Artifactory using curl?

Tags: curl, artifactory, devops

Working on a way to pull down the latest file within an Artifactory repo. I so far have this to check for the latest file

`curl -v -H 'X-JFrog-Art-Api:KEY' "Path-to/?lastModified"`

Is there a way to incorporate these results with another curl command using a -o to pull it down?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I download last artifact in Artifactory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41362345/how-can-i-download-last-artifact-in-artifactory)

Answer (score 1):

Check [Eyal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47400809/402053) to the similar question. JFrog CLI is the easiest way:

`jfrog rt dl  "my-local-repo/all-my-frogs/" --sort-by=created
--sort-order=desc --limit=1`